# I need to log-log my model in R. However, I keep getting the same error

Tags: r, linear-regression

```
#Code implemented 
model2 <- lm(log(Life_Expectancy_Data_2$`Life expectancy`) ~ 
             log(Life_Expectancy_Data_2$`Adult Mortality`) + 
             log(Life_Expectancy_Data_2$Alcohol) + 
             log(Life_Expectancy_Data_2$BMI) + 
             log(Life_Expectancy_Data_2$GDP) + 
             log(Life_Expectancy_Data_2$Schooling) + 
             log(Life_Expectancy_Data_2$`Income composition of resources`)
```

Error message

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
> NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your data, do you have any zeros/missing values in your data?

Comment: Hey! Yeah, I have zeros/missing or NA in my data set. For that, I use ' use = "complete.obs" ' . Does that help? Thanks :)

Comment: That helps for the missing values, but logs are not defined for zeros, so you will need to do something else for the zeros.

Comment: Thanks! Any recommendations? Is the syntax correct? If so, would it be a problem with the data set?

Comment: That is a whole other can of worms, better suited for cross validated, see [How should I transform non-negative data including zeros?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros).

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help!

Comment: Worth a comment that you should not use `Life_Expectancy_Data_2$` format but just use the variable names and the `data=` argument in `lm` -- this will make it a lot easier to use the model for predictions etc. You will also find it easier if you use syntactically correct names; see `?make.names`